# Laravel Backpack - Eloquent trying to insert data in a wrong column name after database column rename

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

*I'm facing a problem to save data by eloquent right after rename the database column name.*

The column name was changed inside of the migration. The migration was carried out and the name in the database now is ok.

In the model, the column name was also changed to the new name.
But for some reason, when I try to insert a new record into the database, Laravel is complaining about the column name, it's trying to use the old name instead of the new name.

I'm currently using PHP 7 with Laravel 5.8 and Postgres as database. My environment is running on docker.

**I already tried to clear the cache but it does not solved my issue. 
Composer dump-autoload was also carried out but nothing changed.**

This is the error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42703)
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "name" does not exist LINE 1
```

Is import to say that i'm using Laravel Backpack.

Comment: Please show the code you have where you're inserting a new record.

Comment: Although you have updated your model with the new column name, it is still possible your code still contains queries to the old column. I recommend using **constants** in your model. This way you can reference these constants when performing a query and don't need to worry about the actual column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible due to cache issue sometimes so it is preferable to run following five commands after you do some changes to your migration or env file and Laravel isnt working as expected. Here is full explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1ynDMC8UGg

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Please try these and see if it works after.

Comment: This was the solution. But in order to work was necessary to run those comands inside of the docker container.

Comment: usually from command line in the root of the project works fine for me. Anyways I am glad it worked for ya

Answer (score 0):

Please update your model and please also try with fluent query for testing like:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(array('name'=>'xyz'));
```